# Output of Reduce processed by ToRules - how to preserve sublist structure?

Tags: list-manipulation, output

I have some output from reduce as follows:

```
solutions = 

{(m1 == -4 && m2 == 3 && m3 == 5 && m4 == -3) || (m1 == -4 && 
    m2 == 5 && m3 == 5 && m4 == -4) || (m1 == 0 && m2 == 1 && 
    m3 == -3 && m4 == 4), (m1 == -3 && m2 == 5 && m3 == 3 && 
    m4 == -4) || (m1 == 1 && m2 == 0 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 3) || (m1 == 1 && m2 == 1 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 4), (m1 == -5 && m2 == 3 && m3 == 1 && 
    m4 == 0) || (m1 == -5 && m2 == 4 && m3 == 1 && 
    m4 == 1) || (m1 == 3 && m2 == -4 && m3 == -3 && 
    m4 == 5), (m1 == -3 && m2 == 4 && m3 == 0 && 
    m4 == 1) || (m1 == 5 && m2 == -4 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 5) || (m1 == 5 && m2 == -3 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 3), (m1 == -1 && m2 == -1 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 5) || (m1 == -1 && m2 == 0 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 3) || (m1 == 3 && m2 == -5 && m3 == 0 && 
    m4 == 1), (m1 == 0 && m2 == -1 && m3 == -3 && 
    m4 == 5) || (m1 == 4 && m2 == -5 && m3 == 1 && 
    m4 == 1) || (m1 == 4 && m2 == -3 && m3 == 1 && 
    m4 == 0), (m1 == -5 && m2 == 4 && m3 == 4 && 
    m4 == -5) || (m1 == -5 && m2 == 5 && m3 == 4 && 
    m4 == -1) || (m1 == -1 && m2 == 0 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 3), (m1 == -5 && m2 == 3 && m3 == 4 && 
    m4 == -3) || (m1 == -1 && m2 == -1 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 5) || (m1 == -1 && m2 == 4 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 1), (m1 == -4 && m2 == 1 && m3 == -1 && 
    m4 == 4) || (m1 == -4 && m2 == 5 && m3 == -1 && 
    m4 == -1) || (m1 == 4 && m2 == -3 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 3), (m1 == -4 && m2 == 3 && m3 == -1 && 
    m4 == 0) || (m1 == 4 && m2 == -5 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 4) || (m1 == 4 && m2 == -1 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 5), (m1 == 1 && m2 == -4 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 5) || (m1 == 1 && m2 == 1 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 4) || (m1 == 5 && m2 == -3 && m3 == -1 && 
    m4 == 0), (m1 == 1 && m2 == 0 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 3) || (m1 == 5 && m2 == -5 && m3 == -1 && 
    m4 == 4) || (m1 == 5 && m2 == -4 && m3 == -1 && 
    m4 == -1), (m1 == -5 && m2 == 5 && m3 == 4 && 
    m4 == -1) || (m1 == -1 && m2 == 4 && m3 == -4 && 
    m4 == 1) || (m1 == 3 && m2 == -3 && m3 == 0 && 
    m4 == 3) || (m1 == 3 && m2 == 0 && m3 == 0 && 
    m4 == -3), (m1 == -4 && m2 == 1 && m3 == -1 && 
    m4 == 4) || (m1 == 0 && m2 == -3 && m3 == 3 && 
    m4 == 0) || (m1 == 0 && m2 == 3 && m3 == 3 && 
    m4 == -3) || (m1 == 4 && m2 == -1 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 5), (m1 == -3 && m2 == 0 && m3 == 3 && 
    m4 == -3) || (m1 == -3 && m2 == 3 && m3 == 3 && 
    m4 == 0) || (m1 == 1 && m2 == -4 && m3 == -5 && 
    m4 == 5) || (m1 == 5 && m2 == -5 && m3 == -1 && m4 == 4)}
```

Then I use Map on TotalRules giving

```
solutionsrules = Map[ToRules, solutions]

{{m1 -> -4, m2 -> 3, m3 -> 5, m4 -> -3}, {m1 -> -4, m2 -> 5, m3 -> 5, 
  m4 -> -4}, {m1 -> 0, m2 -> 1, m3 -> -3, m4 -> 4}, {m1 -> -3, 
  m2 -> 5, m3 -> 3, m4 -> -4}, {m1 -> 1, m2 -> 0, m3 -> -5, 
  m4 -> 3}, {m1 -> 1, m2 -> 1, m3 -> -5, m4 -> 4}, {m1 -> -5, m2 -> 3,
   m3 -> 1, m4 -> 0}, {m1 -> -5, m2 -> 4, m3 -> 1, m4 -> 1}, {m1 -> 3,
   m2 -> -4, m3 -> -3, m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> -3, m2 -> 4, m3 -> 0, 
  m4 -> 1}, {m1 -> 5, m2 -> -4, m3 -> -4, m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> 5, 
  m2 -> -3, m3 -> -4, m4 -> 3}, {m1 -> -1, m2 -> -1, m3 -> -4, 
  m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> -1, m2 -> 0, m3 -> -4, m4 -> 3}, {m1 -> 3, 
  m2 -> -5, m3 -> 0, m4 -> 1}, {m1 -> 0, m2 -> -1, m3 -> -3, 
  m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> 4, m2 -> -5, m3 -> 1, m4 -> 1}, {m1 -> 4, m2 -> -3,
   m3 -> 1, m4 -> 0}, {m1 -> -5, m2 -> 4, m3 -> 4, 
  m4 -> -5}, {m1 -> -5, m2 -> 5, m3 -> 4, m4 -> -1}, {m1 -> -1, 
  m2 -> 0, m3 -> -4, m4 -> 3}, {m1 -> -5, m2 -> 3, m3 -> 4, 
  m4 -> -3}, {m1 -> -1, m2 -> -1, m3 -> -4, m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> -1, 
  m2 -> 4, m3 -> -4, m4 -> 1}, {m1 -> -4, m2 -> 1, m3 -> -1, 
  m4 -> 4}, {m1 -> -4, m2 -> 5, m3 -> -1, m4 -> -1}, {m1 -> 4, 
  m2 -> -3, m3 -> -5, m4 -> 3}, {m1 -> -4, m2 -> 3, m3 -> -1, 
  m4 -> 0}, {m1 -> 4, m2 -> -5, m3 -> -5, m4 -> 4}, {m1 -> 4, 
  m2 -> -1, m3 -> -5, m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> 1, m2 -> -4, m3 -> -5, 
  m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> 1, m2 -> 1, m3 -> -5, m4 -> 4}, {m1 -> 5, m2 -> -3,
   m3 -> -1, m4 -> 0}, {m1 -> 1, m2 -> 0, m3 -> -5, 
  m4 -> 3}, {m1 -> 5, m2 -> -5, m3 -> -1, m4 -> 4}, {m1 -> 5, 
  m2 -> -4, m3 -> -1, m4 -> -1}, {m1 -> -5, m2 -> 5, m3 -> 4, 
  m4 -> -1}, {m1 -> -1, m2 -> 4, m3 -> -4, m4 -> 1}, {m1 -> 3, 
  m2 -> -3, m3 -> 0, m4 -> 3}, {m1 -> 3, m2 -> 0, m3 -> 0, 
  m4 -> -3}, {m1 -> -4, m2 -> 1, m3 -> -1, m4 -> 4}, {m1 -> 0, 
  m2 -> -3, m3 -> 3, m4 -> 0}, {m1 -> 0, m2 -> 3, m3 -> 3, 
  m4 -> -3}, {m1 -> 4, m2 -> -1, m3 -> -5, m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> -3, 
  m2 -> 0, m3 -> 3, m4 -> -3}, {m1 -> -3, m2 -> 3, m3 -> 3, 
  m4 -> 0}, {m1 -> 1, m2 -> -4, m3 -> -5, m4 -> 5}, {m1 -> 5, 
  m2 -> -5, m3 -> -1, m4 -> 4}}
```

But my output here does not preserve the initial structure in the sense that I want the three initial conditional lists to become three elements of a first sublist and so on - the last three sublists would consist of four elements each.

I hope I am explaining that clearly. I just can't seem to get what I want from Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
solutionsrules = Map[List @* ToRules, expr]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use

```
solutionsrules2 = solutions /. {And | Or -> List, Equal -> Rule};

solutionsrules2 == solutionsrules
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying everything - and obviously not the right thing. Just what I wanted.